# How to compare two text files in C and output the differences in a new text file

Tags: c

I am writing a program that inputs two text files 
`inputtxt1`, 
`inputtxt2`
and output 
`outputtxt` file

In these two files information such as

input txt1

```
S00111111   5           6-Jul-19    09-Aug-19
S00800000   4           1-Jul-19    30-Aug-19
S00000000   1           1-Jul-19    30-Aug-19
```

input txt2

```
S00111111   3           6-Jul-19    09-Aug-19
S00222222   1           20-Jul-19   30-Aug-19
S00000000   1           1-Jul-19    30-Aug-19
```

I am writing a program to input these two txt files and output the differences in SQL queries and the values inside the bracket will change depends on the differences from these text files.

- `DELETE FROM TABLE WHERE TABLE=[] AND TABLE=[]`
- `INSERT INTO TABLE (TABLE1,TABLE2,TABLE3,TABLE4) VALUES ([ ],[],'[2019-08-30] 00:00:00','[2019-07-01] 00:00:00');`
- `DELETE FROM TABLE WHERE TABLE=[] AND TABLE=[4]`
- `INSERT INTO TABLE (TABLE,TABLE) VALUES ([],[4]);`

I wrote my draft in C so what I did id basically a while loop to read each of the line of the first file and each of the line of the second file and output the query.

Here are my two questions:

1. First it, unfortunately, output the file SQL 3 times, I think there is something wrong with my while loop.
2. Secondly, how would I make the program detect that specific character from specific line need to be printed in the query for example number 5 in the first line would detect and add to the value of one of the tables in the query.

```
/* This program will input two text files, output a text file with the differences*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

FILE *in1, *in2, *out;
int a, b;

void main (void)
{
    int c;
    char* singleline [33];
    char* singleline2 [33];

in1 = fopen ("inputtest1.txt", "r"); /* reads from the first file  */
in2 = fopen ("inputtest2.txt", "r"); /* reads from the second file  */
out = fopen ("outputtest3", "w"); /* writes out put to this file */


    // Menu //
    printf ("TSC Support Program\n\n"); 
    printf ("This program compare the two files and output the differences in SQL quries \n");  


    // if the file is empty or something went wrong!
    if (in1 == NULL || in2 == NULL)
        {
            printf("********************Can Not Read File !**************************");
        }
    else
        {



// Checking Every line in the first text file if it equals to the first line of  the text file
        while (!feof(in1)&&!feof(in2))
        {

        //  a = getc(in1);
        //  b = getc(in2);
        a = fgets(singleline, 33,in1);
        b = fgets(singleline2, 33,in2); 

                if (a!=b)
                    {
                        printf("\n SQL will be printed\n");
                        fprintf (out,
        "\n DELETE FROM BADGELINK WHERE BADGEKEY=[27] AND ACCLVLID=75"
        "\nINSERT INTO BADGELINK (BADGEKEY,ACCLVLID,ACTIVATE,DEACTIVATE) VALUES ([27],75,'[2010-08-24] 00:00:00','[2010-12-17] 00:00:00'); \n"
        "\n DELETE FROM BADGE WHERE BADGEKEY=[27] AND ISSUECODE=[75]"
        "\nINSERT INTO BADGE (BADGEKEY,ISSUECODE) VALUES ([27],[1]);\n"

        );
                    }
                else
                    {
                        printf("Something went wrong");
                    }       
        }
                }

fclose(in1);
fclose(in2);
fclose(out);
}
```

It prints the output 5 times
and then it says something went wrong. I am unsure what went wrong.

Comment: This does not compare strings `if (a!=b)`, please read up on `strncmp()`. There must be a duplicate of this by the way, but I admittedly can't find it.

Comment: Save time, enable warnings.  `char* singleline [33]  ... fgets(singleline, 33,in1)` should warn.  --- As well as many others.

Comment: Who suggested `while (!feof(in1)&&!feof(in2))`?

Comment: You're probably going to end up reinventing the standard Unix [`diff`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff) program.  This is a problem that is (a) not easy but (b) well studied.  Modern versions of `diff` (e.g. [GNU diff](https://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/)) let you customize the output in various ways, so you might be able to use one of them to generate your SQL queries out of the box, without having to reinvent the wheel of the diff algorithm.  (But if you want to, don't let me stop you.  I'm an inveterate wheel reinventer myself, and I had fun inventing my own diff algorithm once.)

Comment: Are the IDs in the first column (I assume they're some kind of IDs) guaranteed to be in order?  If so, then when you find a mismatch, it's easy to know whether it represents an insertion or a deletion.  But if they're not in order, this makes it a much harder problem!  (This is the heart of any diff algorithm.)

Comment: what is your "differences" mean? you have( BADGEKEY,ACCLVLID,ACTIVATE,DEACTIVATE)  BADGEKEY same,other diff or ACCLVLID same other diff......

Answer (score 0):

if `(a != b)` does not do what you think it is doing. Check [strncmp()](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=strncmp) or [memcmp()](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=memcmp&sektion=3&apropos=0&manpath=FreeBSD%2012.0-RELEASE%20and%20Ports) library functions.

But if you want to find out the first different character in two strings, the code below would do it for you.

Not tested properly, so take it as a quick prototype.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int strdiff(char *s1, char *s2){
        char *p1 = s1;
        while(*s1++ == *s2++)
                ;
        if (s1 != s2)
                return --s1-p1; /* we have s1++ in the while loop */
        return -1;
}


int main(){
        char *s1="S00111111   5           6-Jul-19    09-Aug-19";
        char *s2="S00111111   3           6-Jul-19    09-Aug-19";
        int i = strdiff(s1,s2);
        printf("%d %c\n",i, s1[i]);
        return 0;
}
```

Mind you, *comparing two files line by line* may turn out to be a bigger mission than it sounds if the two files you are comparing do not have exactly the same lines (with minor differences of course).